# Имеется два запроса. Данные берутся из одной таблицы. Каким образом можно вывести два запроса в один, только названия полей должны быть разные

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select first_name as Служащий from Customers Where first_name='JOHN'

Select  first_name as Коллеги, department_id from Employee
 Where department_id=(Select department_id from Employee Where first_name='JOHN' ) AND 
 first_name<>(Select first_name from Employee Where first_name='JOHN' )
```

UNION не подходит. Мне надо чтоб таблица имела вид: Служащий, Коллеги, ИД отдела

Comment: А "коллеги" в каком виде, если их несколько ? подозреваю что join и какая нибудь замена listagg, например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: просто фамилии. несколько штук.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.first_name, t2.department_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.first_name)
FROM Customers t1, Employee t2, Customers t3
WHERE /* t1.first_name='JOHN' 
  AND */ t1.department_id = t2.department_id
  AND t2.department_id = t3.department_id
  AND t1.first_name != t3.first_name 
GROUP BY t1.first_name
```

Если надо только для одного JOHN-a - раскомментировать условие, но убрать группировку.

Comment: там sql-server, в котором нет group_concat

Comment: Ну слинкует через XML, делов-то...